# ¿Cómo leer el contenido de un txt linea por linea con PHP?

Tags: php, html, txt

Hola necesito leer un txt con PHP linea por linea obteniendo de cada linea texto en posiciones especificas, por ejemplo:

```
Linea 1: Luis Juarez

Linea 2: Paco Mendoza

Linea 3: Pepe Gonzales
```

Solo quiero extraer el nombre que esta en las primeras 4 posiciones
Luis estaría de la posición 0 a la 3, los mismo seria con los otros dos, como hago para que recorra todo el archivo y que solo muestre las posiciones que requiera.

Este es el código que he hecho, pero solo me arroja resultados con la linea 1, no recorre todo el contenido del archivo, agradecería mucho su colaboración gracias

```
<?php 
//Llamar al arcivo
$nombre=$_FILES['archivo']['name'];
$guardado=$_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'];

if (!file_exists('archivos')) {
    mkdir('archivos',0777,true);
    if (file_exists('archivos')) {
        if(move_uploaded_file($guardado, 'archivos/'.$nombre)){
            echo "";
        }else{
            echo "Ocurrio un error con la carga del archivo";
        }
    }
}else{
    if(move_uploaded_file($guardado, 'archivos/'.$nombre)){
    }else{
        echo "Ocurrio un error con la carga del archivo";
    }
}

// Abrir el archivo en modo de sólo lectura:
$arc = fopen('archivos/'.$nombre,"r");

// Recorremos el archivo mostando el contenido de cada línea:
echo file_get_contents('archivos/'.$nombre,null,null,2,18);

fclose($arc);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para leerlo línea a línea podrías probar esto:

```
$arc = fopen('archivos/'.$nombre,"r");
while(! feof($arc))  {
    $linea = fgets($arc);
    echo "Nombre: ".substr($linea, 0, 4);
}
fclose($arc);
```

donde, mediante un bucle [while()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.while.php) y la función [feof()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.feof) vamos avanzando hasta el final del archivo.

Y en cada ciclo léemos cada línea mediante la función [fgets()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.fgets), avanzando el puntero del archivo.

Y le sustraemos una longitud de 4 caracteres, empezando por el principio gracias a la función [substr()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.substr.php)

Comment: Muchísimas gracias de verdad, llevaba horas atorado con eso, me funciono a la prefeccion

Comment: Listo ya la acepte gracia de verdad

Comment: Me alegro pues :-)  Gracias a ti, saludos!

Comment: Otra pregunta

Linea 1: Luis Juarez

Linea 2: Paco Mendoza

Linea 3: Pepe Gonzales

Si quisiera recoger el nombre y tambien el apellido como lo haria, si lo hago dentro del mismo ciclo, el momento de recoger el apellido se salta a la siguiente line y me imprime
Luis Mendoza

Comment: Acabo de modificar mi respuesta para que la linea quede almacenada en la variable $linea y así puedas realizar tantas operaciones como desees después sobre ella en el mismo ciclo. PIensa que cada vez que usas fgets() estás avanzando el puntero dentro del archivo, por eso, si quieres realizar varias operacoines sobre una linea, mejor la guardamos en una variable con un solo fgets() en cada ciclo.

Comment: Eres un  genio muchísimas gracias, ya quedo incluso ya pude recuperar la informacion e insertarla en una base de datos